# How to install Google Chrome for Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, google-chrome, gdebi

While trying to install the .deb applications in Ubuntu 17.04, it shows errors.

- I used dpkg as well :
  `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

  Error :
  [Using dpkg command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8osL.png)

  - I tried to install gdebi from command line as well and theres another error:

  [Trying to install gdebi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skm4K.png)

  - I tried to install gdebi from the Application Store, but nothing happens there.
  - I also downloaded two files of gdebi from Launchpad

    gdebi_0.9.5.7+nmu1.dsc

    gdebi_0.9.5.7+nmu1.tar.xz

but I dont understand what to do with them.

- While trying to update:

  `sudo apt update`

Error :

```
`E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list (Component)
```

E: The list of sources could not be read.
`

Comment: please try `sudo apt update`, then `sudo apt install -f` finally `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: Please post the contents of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`

Comment: these are the contents:      deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/stable main

Comment: Even the update option is not working.

Comment: That's because there's an error in that file

Comment: Okay...so how to deal with that @George

Comment: One moment let me get the correct form of that file

Comment: The line should have been `deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`, but I see yours `deb dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/stable main`. Open that file in an editor like `nano` and add a `#` to the front of that line and run thosecommands I gave earlier

Comment: There's some permission issues with that file, I am unable to rewrite the contents as : `deb dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/stable main` .  Other way around via terminal or something?

Comment: Ok sorry you need to run `sudo nano` to edit it, __please only add a`#` don't change any other thing__

Comment: Yes I did what you just said, now the contents are : `#deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/stable main
`

Comment: Now run the commands I gave you earlier

Comment: Guess what? Its working!! WOW. The update just began. Thank you very much @George.

Comment: Why did we added # to the line?

Comment: That line wasn't formed very well as a result of I guess the botched install of chrome, we simply commented it out to allow it be re-created and or allow updates to go on successfully. About the chrome is that okay too?

Comment: Yeah, everything is working great! Got gdebi and Chrome as well, now its working all right. Thanks again! :)

Comment: okay let me post an answer for your acceptance :)

Answer (score 2):

By far the simplest way to get up and running is to open a shell and make sure that libappindicator1 is installed. I reinstalled 5 minutes ago, and this was all I needed on a fresh 16.04.3, which I believe is going to behave exactly like 17.04.

```
    sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```

After that is set you can either download and use

```
    sudo dpkg -i google-blahblah.deb
```

Or simply choose install from the website, and let the package manager do the work. I prefer the second option even though I like to use the CLI whenever possible, its just faster.

Note that if things act weird, say during installing libappindicator something gives an error or complains and does not finish cleanly, use the command already listed to fix the install problems, like so

```
    sudo apt-get install -f
```

Make sure you don't issue it with any other parameters. I admittedly had to issue this command myself even though my files are virgin right now. Chow.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this error

```
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list (Component)
```

The normal content of that file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` should be:

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Based on the instruction in this file we can just comment out that entry and it will be recreated on update, so

1. Open the file with:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.lis.d/google.list
   ```
2. Added `#` to the beginning of the line `deb dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/stable main`
3. Now run the following commands sequentially:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install -f 
   sudo apt dist-upgrade
   ```

Now your upgrade should go as normal.